# C: Saving dynamic array of structs along with string

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct

I am trying to save a struct (listed)

```
typedef struct tupleStruct{

    int element[eMax];
    char * id;
    int eCount;

}tuple_t;

typedef struct {
    tuple_t * array;
    int used;
    int size;
} DynamicArray;
```

As part of an assignment I was instructed to save tuples that are stored in a dynamic array in a file. Unfortunately since strings don't exist in c (at least not like they do in other languages). Whenever I try to save an element of the dynamic array in a file, the string is not stored or loaded properly as it's seen as a pointer. I've even tried by initializing it like so in the struct:

```
char id[256];
```

Is there any way possible to save the struct and the string in a single file? (Given that I need to store multiple of these)

Edit: Saving and loading code

Loading

```
DynamicArray loadAllTuples(){

    FILE *filePointer;

    DynamicArray tempArray;

    if((filePointer=fopen("SavedTuples.bin","rb"))==NULL)
    {
        fputs("Something went wrong while loading!\nA blank Array will be loaded instead\n", stderr);
        setbuf(stdout, 0);

        //In case of error, blank array is initalised and loaded
        fclose(filePointer);

        intialiseDynamicArray(&tempArray);

        return tempArray;
    }



    fread(&tempArray, sizeof(DynamicArray),1,filePointer);

    //Freeing filePointer memory
    free(filePointer);

    return tempArray;

}
```

saving

```
void saveAllTuples(DynamicArray ToSave){

    trimArray(&ToSave,0); //Removing extra space from array

    FILE * filePointer;

    if((filePointer=fopen("SavedTuples.bin","wb"))==NULL)
    {
        fputs("Something went wrong while saving!\n", stderr);
        setbuf(stdout, 0);
        return;
    }

    fwrite(&ToSave, sizeof(ToSave), 1,filePointer);
    fclose(filePointer);

}
```

called by

```
saveAllTuples(dynaArray);
```

and

```
dynaArray=loadAllTuples();
```

Comment: The easiest way if you can give the string a fixed maximum size like 256 in your example.

Comment: @Lundin I tried that, however even in that scenario it still gets treated as a pointer.

Comment: strings do exist in c .. not entirely sure what you're asking. You can use [`fprintf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf) to write a string to a file. It works just like `printf` except the first argument is a `FILE*`

Comment: Show us the code where you're writing the output and we can see where you're going wrong.

Comment: Probably you save/load it incorrectly from the file. Please post the relevant code with file I/O.

Comment: @yano what I meant is that they don't exists in their usual format so to speak, basically I need to save a struct that contains a string to a file

Comment: a `DynamicArray` contains a pointer and 2 `int`s .. it's size is probably going to be 16 bytes (8 for the pointer, plus 4 each for the `int`s). It's not automatically going to write what the pointer is pointing to, it's going to be a little more work that a one-liner to write all the data in your struct. `array` points to a `tuple_t` and a `tuple_t` has a `char` pointer as well that you'll need to follow. And as you've noted, writing the pointer value to file is useless, you need to write the data it points to in order to be able to read it back.

Comment: Are you suggesting writing the elements separately for each tuple_t element?

Comment: yes, you have to write _data_ to the file. If your struct only had data members (3 `int`s for instance), you could get away with the one-liner `fwrite`. Writing a pointer value to file will give you nothing when it's time to read that data back. That pointer value is some virtual address that is meaningless as soon as the data it points to goes out of scope. You're going to have to write each data element to file in a way that's completely recoverable when you read it back, there's not a single right way to do it, you'll need to come up with a file format.

Comment: here's an example of one way to write a string (your `char *`) to file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182876/how-to-write-a-string-to-a-file-in-c . After that, you still need to write the `element` array and `eCount`. Should you write the size of `element` too so that's recoverable, or is that fixed/able to be deduced from the data? You'll also need to write `used` and `size` from the `DynamicArray`. You'll need to write it all in a specific way such that the reader knows the format and can recover all the data exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing the whole struct in one go, write out the various parts of it utilising your knowledge of what they contain. So for example, if `eCount` is the amount of values in `element` you could write this

```
fwrite(&ToSave.eCount,sizeof(int), 1, filepointer);
fwrite(ToSave.element,sizeof(int), ToSave.eCount, filepointer);
```

and then to store the string component

```
size_t length=strlen(ToSave.id);
fwrite(&length,sizeof(int), 1, filepointer);
fwrite(ToSave.id,sizeof(char), length, filepointer);
```

Note: `sizeof(char)` is typically always 1, so you could assume that and put 1 rather than `sizeof(char)` but I find it makes the code look more uniform to leave it in.

And then you reverse the process when you do the reading

```
fwrite(&ToLoad.eCount,sizeof(int), 1, filepointer);
fwrite(ToLoad.element,sizeof(int), ToLoad.eCount, filepointer);
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

To whom it may help in the future: So after asking around a bit, some people got it to work by treating the identifier as an array instead of a pointer.

```
char id[256];
```

I said this didn't work before, but it was probably due to another mistake which I didn't spot. Saving each tuple will keep the string identifier intact as long as an array is used.